# Column in pandas conditional on average of other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to make a set of synthetic data. I am using Python 3.5.2 . I start by defining it as so:

```
#Make Synthetic data (great again?)
#synth X
data=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100,5), columns= 'x1','x2','x3','x4','x5']) 
def div10(x):
    if x<0:
        return -x/5
    else:
        return x/10
data=data.applymap(div10)
```

From here I want to define a new column that is the string 'dead' if the hyperbolic tangent of the mean of the Xs in the row is greater than .15 and 'alive otherwise:

```
data['Y']=data.apply( lambda x:'dead' if np.tanh(data.mean(axis=1))>.15 else     'alive',axis=1)
```

I am told `ValueError: ('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().', 'occurred at index 0')` When I check `np.tanh(data.mean(axis=1))>.15` I get a list of bools.

I have also tried map, but `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map'`

Comment: Try removing axis=1 from the mean function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

learn to use where statements for better and faster code.

```
np.where(np.tanh(np.mean(np.where(data<0, -data / 5, data / 10), axis=1)) > .15, 'dead', 'alive')
```

Lets break this into chunks. where statements can operate on multidimensional data such as the dataframe that you have. They take a conditional and return the first argument after the comma when true and the second when false

```
step1 = np.where(data<0, -data / 5, data / 10)
```

There is no need to use `apply` as numpy has a vectorized mean function that you can apply by row (axis=1)

```
step2 = np.mean(step1, axis=1)
```

Now you have one dimensional data. take hyperbolic tangent

```
step3 = np.tanh(step2)
```

Finally use another where statement to get dead or alive condition

```
np.where(step3 > .15, 'dead', 'alive')
```

Comment: Thanks so much! As I was leaving work all I could think was "Wow this would be so easy if something like excels "if" function was in python...and that's exactly what it is.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you are using the 'x' specified in your lambda function. Also since x is a series (the row in the data frame) axis=1 won't work.

`data['Y']=data.apply(lambda x:'dead' if np.tanh(x.mean())>.15 else 'alive',axis=1)`